# Turn List into String with vowels and 'and' at the end

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a string from a list. However, I want it to be arranged in a way that makes sense, so instead of the string being "I have apple, banana, Papa's citrus.", I want it to be "I have an apple, a banana, and Papa's citrus.". (Strings being "apple", "banana", and "Papa's citrus".)

I'd rather not change the strings making up my list; The thing I'm working on is a mod that changes the list depending on what other mods are enabled, so adding 'and' to the last string of each group won't work very well.

In all, the code I want would turn a list into a string, adding 'a' in front of words beginning with consonants, 'an' in front of words with vowels, and neither in front of words with apostrophes.

Thanks!

Comment: "In all, the code I want would..." This is too broad for Stack Overflow. You need to try for yourself and ask a question when you cannot go forward, *posting the code here so we can guide you from there*

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: The question is absolutely legit, not too broad and trying randomly won't help

Comment: @Stilgar Um what?

Comment: @DavidG I am replying to the users above who suggest that the question is low quality. I disagree.

Comment: @Stilgar That's what I thought. The question is too broad because OP hasn't tried anything yet and SO is not a code writing service. "Trying randomly" is exactly what should be done. And nobody said the question was low quality, just that it's not a good fit for here.

Comment: @Stilgar So now we can just dump requirements and wait for someone to answer? Nice, what's the site called? I must be new... Also, if it isn't low quality nor anything, why didn't you upvote? Or why didn't you @'tag me? I didn't say it is low quality either

Comment: I forgot to upvote probably because I am looking for a solution.

Comment: @Stilgar So you think this question shows research effort?

Comment: Not really but I don't think research here is obvious especially for non-native English speaker. I am not even sure what to Google here.

Comment: @Stilgar Hover over the upvote button, does this question fulfil all of the requirements of the tooltip? You've just said it doesn't...

Comment: @Stilgar How to program in C# ?

Comment: Sorry, all of you. Probably should've looked more into this rather than posting with the hopes of the answer magically appearing. I'll probably try and look into this more myself. Admittedly, I should have posted code, but I've probably wasted enough of you guys' time already. Again, sorry.

Comment: @CreeperdaSnek You can still [edit] your question to improve it, that's our ultimate goal here :)

Comment: The only thing I'd do differently if I asked the question would be to point out that the obvious method is not correct as you cannot know from the spelling of an English word if it starts with a vowel - honest vs human.

Comment: Ummm, I know pretty well from the spelling if the word starts with a vowel.  There are exceptions to the rule regarding 'a' and 'an' though, if that's what you were referring to.

Comment: I doubt you know that from the first letter though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what your input looks like, but it might be something like this console application. However, English is not my first language, so I might be terribly wrong:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> strings = new List<string>
    {
        "apple",
        "banana",
        "Papa's citrus"
    };

    var lastNdx = strings.Count - 1;
    var sentence = "I have " + String.Join(", ", 
        strings.Select((s, ndx) =>
        {
            var ls = s.ToLower();
            string ret = "";
            if ("aeiou".Contains(ls[0]))
                ret = "an " + s;
            else if (ls.Contains("\'"))
                ret = s;
            else ret = "a " + s;
            if (ndx == lastNdx)
                ret = "and " + ret;
            return ret;
        }).ToArray() );

    Console.WriteLine(sentence);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for @Stilgar. It is somewhat complicated, so I made it a second answer.

Download the latest version of the [CMU Pronunciation Dictionary files](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/) and store them in a folder. Set the path in the `CMUDictExt` class to use that folder:

```
public static class CMUDictExt {
    const string cmuFolder = @"D:\";
    static IEnumerable<string> CMUFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(cmuFolder, "cmudict-*");
    static Regex cmudictName = new Regex(@"cmudict-(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z]?)+\.?(.*)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    static string CMUFile(string ext) => CMUFiles.First(f => cmudictName.Match(f).Groups[1].Value == ext);

    static Dictionary<string, string> phones;
    static Dictionary<string, string[]> pronunciations;
    public static ILookup<string, string> SymbolWords;
    static HashSet<string> exceptions;

    static CMUDictExt() {
        phones = File.ReadLines(CMUFile("phones"))
                     .Select(l => l.Split('\t'))
                     .ToDictionary(pa => pa[0], pa => pa[1]);

        pronunciations = File.ReadLines(CMUFile(""))
                             .Where(l => !l.StartsWith(";;;"))
                             .Where(l => Char.IsLetter(l[0]))
                             .Select(l => l.Split("  ").ToArray())
                             .ToDictionary(wg => wg[0].ToLowerInvariant(), wg => wg[1].Split(' '));

        SymbolWords = pronunciations.SelectMany(wp => wp.Value.Select(s => (Word: wp.Key, s)))
                                    .ToLookup(wp => wp.s, wp => wp.Word);
        exceptions = pronunciations.Where(wp => (wp.Key.StartsWithVowel() ^ wp.Value[0].Phone() == "vowel")).Select(wp => wp.Key).ToHashSet();
    }

    public static string Phone(this string aSymbol) => phones.GetValueOrDefault(aSymbol.UpTo(ch => Char.IsDigit(ch)), String.Empty);

    static string[] emptyStringArray = new string[] {};
    public static string[] Pronunciation(this string aWord) => pronunciations.GetValueOrDefault(aWord.ToLowerInvariant(), emptyStringArray);
    public static bool HasPronunciation(this string aWord) => pronunciations.GetValueOrDefault(aWord.ToLowerInvariant(), null) != null;

    static readonly HashSet<char> vowels = "aeiou".ToHashSet<char>();
    public static bool StartsWithVowel(this string w) => vowels.Contains(w[0]);
    public static bool BeginsWithVowelSound(this string aWord) => exceptions.Contains(aWord) ? !aWord.StartsWithVowel() : aWord.StartsWithVowel(); // guess if not found
}
```

Using similar extension methods as before:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) => new HashSet<T>(source);
    public static IEnumerable<T> Leave<T>(this ICollection<T> src, int drop) => src.Take(src.Count - drop);
    public static IEnumerable<T> Drop<T>(this ICollection<T> src, int drop) => (drop < 0) ? src.Leave(-drop) : src.Skip(drop);
    public static T MinBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> keySelector, Comparer<TKey> keyComparer) => src.Aggregate((a, b) => keyComparer.Compare(keySelector(a), keySelector(b)) < 0 ? a : b);
    public static T MinBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> keySelector) => src.Aggregate((a, b) => Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(keySelector(a), keySelector(b)) < 0 ? a : b);
}

public static class StringExt {
    public static string UpTo(this string s, Regex stopRE) {
        var m = stopRE.Match(s);
        if (m.Success)
            return s.Substring(0, m.Index);
        else
            return s;
    }
    public static string UpTo(this string s, Func<char, bool> testfn) {
        var m = s.Select((ch, Index) => new { ch, Index, Success = testfn(ch) }).FirstOrDefault(cit => cit.Success);
        if (m != null && m.Success)
            return s.Substring(0, m.Index);
        else
            return s;
    }

    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string sep) => String.Join(sep, strings.ToArray());
    public static bool EndsWithOneOf(this string s, params string[] endings) => endings.Any(e => s.EndsWith(e));

    public static IEnumerable<string> Split(this string s, params string[] seps) => s.Split(StringSplitOptions.None, seps);

    public static IEnumerable<string> Split(this string s, StringSplitOptions so, params string[] seps) {
        int pos = 0;
        do {
            var sepPos = seps.Select(sep => new { pos = s.IndexOf(sep, pos) < 0 ? s.Length : s.IndexOf(sep, pos), len = sep.Length }).MinBy(pl => pl.pos);
            if (sepPos.pos > pos || so == StringSplitOptions.None)
                yield return s.Substring(pos, sepPos.pos - pos);
            pos = sepPos.pos + sepPos.len;
        } while (pos <= s.Length);
    }
    public static string FirstWord(this string phrase) => phrase.UpTo(ch => Char.IsWhiteSpace(ch));

    public static bool IsAllLetters(this string s) => s.All(ch => Char.IsLetter(ch)); // faster than Regex
}


public static class DictionaryExt {
    public static TV GetValueOrDefault<TK, TV>(this IDictionary<TK, TV> dict, TK key, TV defaultValue) => dict.TryGetValue(key, out TV value) ? value : defaultValue;
}
```

You can now create some custom extensions to handle parts of the problem:

```
public static class FruitExt {
    public static bool IsPossessive(this string phrase) => phrase.FirstWord().EndsWithOneOf("'s", "'");

    public static string WithIndefiniteArticle(this string phrase) => (phrase.FirstWord().BeginsWithVowelSound() ? "an " : "a ") + phrase;
    public static string ArticleOrPossessive(this string phrase) => phrase.IsPossessive() ? phrase : phrase.WithIndefiniteArticle();
}
```

Now the answer is calculated the same as before, but it handles many English language exceptions properly before defaulting to checking for a vowel:

```
var ans = ("I have " + src.Drop(-1).Select(w => w.ArticleOrPossessive()).Join(", ") + " and " + src.Last().ArticleOrPossessive() + ".");
```

Sample output:

```
I have an apple, a banana, Papa's citrus, an honest judge, a highchair, a university and an understanding.
```

Comment: Now that's more like it! :)

Comment: @Stilgar Added some sample output and refined it a little.

Comment: BTW I don't need this just curious what a proper solution would be :)

Comment: @Stilgar Me, too :)

Answer (score 0):

Using some convenient extension methods:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) => new HashSet<T>(source);
    public static IEnumerable<T> Leave<T>(this ICollection<T> src, int drop) => src.Take(src.Count - drop);
    public static IEnumerable<T> Drop<T>(this ICollection<T> src, int drop) => (drop < 0) ? src.Leave(-drop) : src.Skip(drop);
}

public static class StringExt {
    public static string UpTo(this string s, Regex stopRE) {
        var m = stopRE.Match(s);
        if (m.Success)
            return s.Substring(0, m.Index);
        else
            return s;
    }

    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string sep) => String.Join(sep, strings.ToArray());
    public static bool EndsWithOneOf(this string s, params string[] endings) => endings.Any(e => s.EndsWith(e));
}
```

You can then create some custom extension methods to break the problem down:

```
public static class FruitExt {
    public static readonly HashSet<char> consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz".ToHashSet();
    public static bool BeginsWithConsonant(this string w) => consonants.Contains(w[0]);

    public static bool IsPossessive(this string w) => w.UpTo(new Regex(@"\s")).EndsWithOneOf("'s", "'");

    public static string WithIndefiniteArticle(this string w) => (w.BeginsWithConsonant() ? "a " : "an ") + w;
    public static string ArticleOrPossessive(this string w) => w.IsPossessive() ? w : w.WithIndefiniteArticle();
}
```

Note that `BeginsWithConsonant` fails for those (four?) words that begin with Y as a vowel - if it bothers you, you could add exceptions to the method.

Now the answer is fairly straight forward LINQ:

```
var ans = ("I have "+src.Drop(-1).Select(w => w.ArticleOrPossessive()).Join(", ")+" and "+src.Last().ArticleOrPossessive()+".");
```

`Drop` and `Last` aren't particularly efficient in the general case, but since we know we are using a `List`, they are fine (and the data is going to be short regardless).

Comment: If adjectives are allowed in his strings then the amount of words where the method would be incorrect grows quite a bit.

Comment: @Stilgar How, so? "a red apple" is still valid as is "an orange orange", no?

Comment: for example honest vs high

Comment: @Stilgar I added an answer just for you :)